# Can a enum value in phpmyadmin be like this? 'Readme'=>1

Tags: php, mysql, enums, phpmyadmin

In this, I would see Readme, but the value would be set to 1

Is this possible?

edit;
Sorry. Basically I have a site. It's navigation is in the database. It need to display nav items depening on the users state, like, logged in , admin, blogger, not loggin, and indepenant. These work, however I would like to move from numerical values to human readable. I would like to keep my script the same. So, basicly, can I make the enum Test equal to 1, like a php array?

Comment: phpmyadmin is merely an abstraction of mysql so are you wanting enumerated types in your DB table or are you talking about development for phpmyadmin?

Comment: Hi. I am talking about mysql, but I am using phpmyadmin as a manager. Basically, I would like to see value names that make sense, instead of -1,0,1,2,3 for not logged in,login not matter, logged in, admin, blogger (It's for my navigation table)

Comment: Here is an example of a bad question. No thought has been made to enlightening us on your difficulties or your requirements. You ask the question as if we all speak your prof's language and know exactly what you need. WHO WHAT WHERE WHEN WHY HOW.

Comment: Sorry. Basically I have a site. It's navigation is in the database. It need to display nav items depening on the users state, like, logged in , admin, blogger, not loggin, and indepenant. These work, however I would like to move from numerical values to human readable. I would like to keep my script the same. So, basicly, can I make the enum Test equal to 1, like a php array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface you're using has no way of assigning symbolic names to values like you describe.

However, you can use a **lookup table** so you can associate a string name with each numeric value.  That is, you can continue to store values like -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 in your database table, but you would create *another* table to map those values into strings.  Then when you want to show the human-readable names, you would do that as a join to the lookup table.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I just ended changing my script.